How to send a single receipt in multiple donations?
Any possibilities have to get a single receipt from multiple donation receipt in civicrm?

See

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous/#thank-you-letters
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous/#grouped-contribution-thank-you-letters

Choose group by contact, and you have a choice of how the multiple get listed.
